# Tippy js is not getting added to window object

Tags: velo, tippyjs

i add this script to codepen and in wix website, in codepen it's working but not in wix website

in the script code i add this code to add tippy.js in the website

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.onload = function () {
  console.log("popperjs load!!");
  console.log(window);

  var script2 = document.createElement('script');
  script2.onload = function () {
    console.log("tippy.js load!!");
    console.log(window);


    tippy("#aulingo-call-widget", {
      content: "My tooltips!"
    });
  };
  script2.src = 'https://unpkg.com/tippy.js@6';
  document.body.appendChild(script2);
};
script.src = 'https://unpkg.com/@popperjs/core@2';
document.body.appendChild(script);
```

it's working in codepen and added the tippy in window object
[image]
[image]

but in wix website, the tippy is window object not being added
[image]
[image]

codepen
https://codepen.io/rupakbarman/pen/JjepRoJ

wix website
https://www.dev-site-5x6816.wixdev-sites.org/

see both using same script but in wix website i am getting error in console saying tippy is not defined